# Derby/JavaDB: TIMESTAMP and BIGINT data types - which is better to store the date?

Tags: java, sql, derby, javadb

I'm a little bit confused - I want to store the date in JavaDB/Derby database, but which data type is better to use?

I can simply store `Long` like `System.currentTimeMillis()` and save it to database in `BIGINT` format. Later I can format it as I want.

Or I can store it like `TIMESTAMP('1962-09-23 03:23:34.234')` using `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Which way is more efficient?

Comment: what is easier for you in your program? ie, which will result in less work for you to format it into a usable string for your program? I wouldn't worry about the database side, modern databases are very smart and will mostly take care of themselves. Unless, of course, if you have measured this to be a bottleneck in your program. As an aside, you may want to check into H2 Database, it's extraordinarily fast, is portable, and written in pure java. IMHO it is much better than Derby.

Comment: Go for a real `timestamp` column, it's the best way to ensure that only valid dates are stored. You can't ensure that with a `bigint` column. Btw: I would prefer HSQLDB over Derby or H2

Comment: The application does not require lot's of SQL operations, so I've chosen JavaDB as free for commercial projects. In this case I prefer `BIGINT`, since I need only to check/calculate time difference. Thanks.

Comment: The big question is. How do you intend to use the the stored value? Depending on your business needs it can range from a simple numeric type all the way to UTC Time + Time Zone name(as CHAR / VARCHAR Colum) + Real Offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc for the [TIMESTAMP data type](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj27620.html) and the doc for [implementation notes](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/JDBCImplementation.html#Derby+SQL+TIMESTAMP) both say that Derby uses [nanosecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution. That suggests a 64-bit integer, but I don't know Derby’s implementation. If you truly care, look at the source code.

Why would you *not* use TIMESTAMP? The job of the database is to manage data, so let it. You should not be trying to jerry-rig the data types without a very important reason. A vague concern about "efficiency" is micro-managing the database server’s job.

Furthermore, your question is vague. What does "efficiency" mean? Less space used in storage? Less space used in memory? Advantages in indexing? Faster queries? Faster writes? But, again, those concerns are [premature optimization](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) (a bad thing) until you’ve identified a specific bottleneck.

There are advantages to storing a date-time value in a date-time data type, otherwise that data type would not have been added to the database’s repertoire. One important benefit of using TIMESTAMP as intended is that it knows how to parse strings as date-time values.